# R ggplot - How to increase the space between 0 and y values

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm adding data labels to my visuals and whenever I have values close to zero my data labels are cut off in proximity of the y axis. See an example in the image below. Is there a way to increase the space between the 0 value and the Y axis values?

Code for the example below:

```
AgencyComposition <- data_frame(
                      Agency = c("Unassigned", "SOFTEL", "HHS", "BESTLIFE")
                      Users = c(1, 40, 3, 2)
)

AgencyComposition
```

And here's the visual:

```
V_agencycomposition <- AgencyComposition %>% 
                            ggplot(
                              aes(
                                x = Users, 
                                y = Agency
                              )
                            ) +
                        geom_col(
                            aes(
                              fill = "Users"
                            ), 
                            alpha = .8
                          ) +
                        labs(
                          x = "Number of users",
                          y = "Agency",
                          color = "User count"
                        ) +
                        geom_label(
                            aes(label = Users), 
                            hjust = 1.2
                        ) +
                        theme(legend.position = "bottom")

V_agencycomposition
```

Thanks in advance!

[image: Example of visual with labels]

Comment: You can add `xlim(c(-2, 40))` to change the x axis limits

Comment: Change `hjust` to `hjust = 0` in `geom_label`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `expand` inside `scale_x_continuous`. Here, I've used `c(0.1, 0)`, but if you want a larger gap on the left hand side you can make the 0.1 as large as you like.

```r
AgencyComposition %>%

ggplot(
  aes(
    x = Users, 
    y = Agency
  )
) +
  geom_col(
    aes(
      fill = "Users"
    ), 
    alpha = .8
  ) +
  labs(
    x = "Number of users",
    y = "Agency",
    color = "User count"
  ) +
  geom_label(
    aes(label = Users), 
    hjust = 1.2
  ) +
  scale_x_continuous(
    expand = c(0.1, 0)
  ) +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom")

V_agencycomposition
```

[image]